Line breaks do not fit well in mathmode
I'm writing a formula in mathmode but the line breaks don't wrap properly. I've tried \newline, \brea, \ and \hfill and none of them work. What can I do to make the line breaks wrap properly?
Thank you very much.
$<\hat{x}^2> = \frac{\int \tilde{\Psi}\hat{x}^2 \tilde{\Psi}d \tau}{\int\tilde{\Psi} *\tilde{Psi} d \tau} = N^4\int_{-a}^a \left(x^2-a^2\right)^2 \hat{x}^2\left(x^2-a^2\right)^2 dx = N^4\int_{-a}^a x^{10}-4a^2x^8+6a^4x^6-4a^6a^6x^4+a^8x^2dx = N^4\left.\left(\frac{x^{11}}{11}- \newline  \frac{4a^2x^9}{9}+\frac{6a^4x^7}{7}-\frac{4a^6x^5}{5}+\frac{a^8x^3}{3}\right)\right]_{-a}^a = N^4\left[\left(\frac{a^{11}}{11}- \break \frac{4a^{11}}{9}+\frac{6a^{11}}{7}-\frac{4a^{11}}{5}+\frac{a^{11}}{3}\right)- \newline \left(-\frac{a^{11}}{11}+\frac{4a^{11}}{9}-\frac{6a^{11}}{7}+\frac{4a^{11}}{5}-\frac{a^{11}}{3}\right)\right] = \frac{315}{256a^9}\frac{256a^{11}}{3456}=\frac{35a^2}{384}$


Please provide complete small document with your equation. Your equation is very long, do you thing about to wrote it as displayed equation in one of amsmath environments?

as you can see in your image <\hat{x}> does not produce angle brackets but less than and greater than, use \langle and \rangle

you need to remove the \left...\right as tex can not break a line within those commands, but you will not produce readable output from automatic linebreaking, here better to use an amsmath display such as \begin{align*} and align on the = with &=

I recommend you switch to using an align* environment (provided by the amsmath package). That way, display-style math mode instead of text-style math mode will be the default, the spacing between lines will be a bit more generous, and it'll be straightforward to select alignment points in each row.
Incidentally, I think you're missing a pair of parentheses in row 3.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'align*' environment

\begin{document}

\addtolength\jot{3pt}
\begin{align*}
\langle\hat{x}^2\rangle 
&= \frac{\int \tilde{\Psi}\hat{x}^2\tilde{\Psi} \, d\tau}%
        {\int\tilde{\Psi}*\tilde{\Psi} \, d\tau} \\
&= N^4\int_{-a}^a {(x^2-a^2)}^2 \hat{x}^2 {(x^2-a^2)}^2 \,dx \\
&= N^4\int_{-a}^a x^{10}-4a^2 x^8 +6a^4 x^6 -4a^6 a^6 x^4 +a^8 x^2 \,dx \\
&= N^4\biggl(\frac{x^{11}}{11} - \frac{4a^2x^9}{9}
   +\frac{6a^4x^7}{7}-\frac{4a^6x^5}{5}
   +\frac{a^8x^3}{3}\biggr)\bigg]_{-a}^a \\
&= N^4\biggl\{\biggl(\frac{a^{11}}{11}
   -\frac{4a^{11}}{9}+\frac{6a^{11}}{7}
   -\frac{4a^{11}}{5}+\frac{a^{11}}{3}\biggr)\\
&\qquad -\biggl(-\frac{a^{11}}{11}+\frac{4a^{11}}{9}
   -\frac{6a^{11}}{7}+\frac{4a^{11}}{5}
   -\frac{a^{11}}{3}\biggr)\biggr\} \\
&= \frac{315}{256a^9}\frac{256a^{11}}{3456}
   =\frac{35a^2}{384}
\end{align*}

\end{document}


Addendum: If for some reason you can't abide an align* environment, I suggest you place the entire equation in a \parbox.

Speaking for myself (who else?), I'd say that the align* solution is a lot easier to read.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'align*' environment
\usepackage{setspace} % for '\setstretch' macro
\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\setstretch{2.75} % need to increase the line spacing

\parbox{0.9\textwidth}{\raggedright%
\hangindent=15pt\hangafter=1 % automatic hanging indentation
$\displaystyle % use displaystyle rather than textstyle math
\langle\hat{x}^2\rangle 
= \frac{\int \tilde{\Psi}\hat{x}^2\tilde{\Psi} \, d\tau}
       {\int\tilde{\Psi}*\tilde{\Psi} \, d\tau} 
= N^4\int_{-a}^a {(x^2-a^2)}^2 \hat{x}^2 {(x^2-a^2)}^2 \,dx 
= N^4\int_{-a}^a x^{10}-4a^2 x^8 +6a^4 x^6 -4a^6 a^6 x^4 +a^8 x^2 \,dx 
= N^4\biggl(\frac{x^{11}}{11} - \frac{4a^2x^9}{9}
   +\frac{6a^4x^7}{7}-\frac{4a^6x^5}{5}
   +\frac{a^8x^3}{3}\biggr)\bigg]_{-a}^a 
= N^4\biggl\{\biggl(\frac{a^{11}}{11}
   -\frac{4a^{11}}{9}+\frac{6a^{11}}{7}
   -\frac{4a^{11}}{5}+\frac{a^{11}}{3}\biggr)\allowbreak
   -\biggl(-\frac{a^{11}}{11}+\frac{4a^{11}}{9}
   -\frac{6a^{11}}{7}+\frac{4a^{11}}{5}
   -\frac{a^{11}}{3}\biggr)\biggr\} 
= \frac{315}{256a^9}\frac{256a^{11}}{3456}
   =\frac{35a^2}{384}
$}

\end{center}
\end{document}

